# Why I am getting 0 at the first index of my newArray in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I made a program to find the same element in two arrays(only once) and take those element in new Array. It is running fine but don't know why I am getting 0 at the first index of my  new arary.
suppose if the answer should like `[9,8]` but it is printing `[0,9,8]`! Can you correct me where I am going wrong?

newArray size should be 2 but  I know it should have started with 0 but I am doing this because if I am starting newArray size with 0 - array out of bound exception will occur.

```
package Arrays;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class InteractionOfTwoArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int arr1[]= new int[] {6,9,8,5};
        int arr2[]= new int[] {9,2,4,1,8};
        
        intersections(arr1,arr2);
    }
    public static void intersections(int arr1[], int arr2[])
    {
        int newArraysize=1;
        for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
        {
            // for getting size of the array
            
            for(int j=0; j<arr2.length; j++)
            {
                if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
                {
                    System.out.println(arr1[i]+" and "+arr2[j]+" match!");
                    newArraysize++;
                    System.out.println(newArraysize);
                }
                                    
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(newArraysize);
        
        int newArray[] = new int[newArraysize];
        
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
        {       
            
            for(int j=0; j<arr2.length;j++)
            {
                if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
                {
                    newArray[i] = arr1[i];
                    System.out.println(arr1[i]+" moved to "+ newArray[i]);
                    break;
                }
                    
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));      
    }

}
```

I have tried to print where I am going wrong but failed to identify.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: 1. You start and initialize `int newArraysize=1;` instead of using zero. So your new array will always be 1 to big currently. 2. You are not using an own counter on where you need to insert in `newArray[i] = arr1[i];`. You can't just use `i` here because the position you might have to insert into your new array might be different than the position they have in `arr1`

Comment: You place the similar elements from both arrays into `newArray` at the index where the element occurs in `arr1` (on the line `newArray[i] = arr1[i];`). You need a separate index variable for writing values into `newArray`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The code is doing exactly what you are instructing it to do. Think about it. You already doing `System.out.println(newArraysize);`, so did you notice that your new array size is calculated 3, whereas it should be 2 because there are only two matching elements in the above arrays? Have you thought what could be the cause of it?</strike>

I see you updated your question, above lines are irrelevant now. See below:

<strike>Secondly,</strike> When you are doing `newArray[i] = arr1[i];` you can stop-debug at this line and inspect the value of `i`. Or just print value of `i`. Your code should be setting values for `0` and `1` indexes of `newArray`.  Why is it setting the values at `1` and `2` indexes?

So you have some logical errors in your code. Somebody may paste corrected logic here in answers, but that might not be healthy for your own learning.

Comment: Thanks ! When people dosent know the know all they can give speech ! First you should know what is the purpose of this site before giving speech!

Comment: @AnishKuls I removed "speech" part of my answer. Please note, I also pinpointed the lines where your code has logical errors. Is it still not clear?

Answer (score -1):

The working version of your code is below. I commented out the description in correspondent lines. But as for reference:

- The `newArray` which keeps the common elements of other two arrays is empty at the first. `int newArraysize=1` was causing the unwanted first `0` element in the final array.
- you need to keep track of the `newArray`'s index separately and not relying on indexes of other arrays. Because when you're looping through `arr1` and find a common element at the index `3` of `arr1`, you were trying to save that element at the same index (3) of `newArray` too. While it's possible that there are only 2 common elements and the `newArray` doesn't have the index `3` at all.

  import java.util.Arrays;

  public class InteractionOfTwoArrays {

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       int arr1[]= new int[] {6,9,8,5};
       int arr2[]= new int[] {9,2,4,1,8};

       intersections(arr1,arr2);
   }
   public static void intersections(int arr1[], int arr2[])
   {
       int newArraysize=0; // <<< Array is empty at first, so the size should be 0 and then get incremented with each match found
       for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
       {
           // for getting size of the array

           for(int j=0; j<arr2.length; j++)
           {
               if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
               {
                   System.out.println(arr1[i]+" and "+arr2[j]+" match!");
                   newArraysize++;
                   System.out.println(newArraysize);
               }

           }
       }

       System.out.println(newArraysize);

       int newArray[] = new int[newArraysize];

       int k = 0; // <<< The index counter for the newArray

       for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
       {       

           for(int j=0; j<arr2.length;j++)
           {
               if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
               {
                   newArray[k++] = arr1[i]; // <<< The index of newArray gets incremented each time.
                   break;
               }

           }
       }

       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));      
   }
  ```

  }